# Possible misunderstanding of Hyperplane separating axis theory (2D ->1D collision detection)

Tags: algorithm, math, 2d, collision-detection

While chewing on my own ideas of how to do collision detection, and researching current algorithms, I came across a theory that people say is fast, and accurate, called Hyperplane separation theorem, and applied to computer science, you gather an object's axis, then project both shapes on the axis, for them to be colliding, all projections must overlap, since I'm doing an AABB-Triangle collision, I used the AABB's axis, as they are much easier to project, but when I began thinking it over, I found a flaw (either in my understanding of the theory, or the theory itself), where both axis can be overlapping, but the two objects non-intersecting, I have attached an image as an example:

[image: Example of flaw in Hyperplane separation]

The first set being an ideal situation, where a collision is found, the second set being the flaw (false positive).

If it is a flaw in the algorithm, could people suggest other algorithms to use for AABB-Triangle collision? I can read almost every programming language, so feel free to post uncommon ones.

Comment: "... feel free to post uncommon ones" ... queue brainf*ck implementation of AABB-triangle...

Comment: It appears that the theorem looks at all possible projections, not just the ones onto the coordinate axes: [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem#Use_in_collision_detection).  It appears you want to project along each facet of your shapes (e.g., you would project south-east along the diagonal of your triangle).

Comment: Running a quick mental check, even if I project along the axes of the faces of the triangle, its still all overlap (false positive)

Comment: Thankyou for pointing out that I need to check both surfaces!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I had a complete misunderstanding :-) I thought it was drawing an axis across a face, it is actually drawing an axis along the face, Thankyou Teepeemm for pointing out that I need to check both surfaces!